# Use instanceof with static inner class from different class

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
public class A {
    static class B {
    }
}

public class C {
   void m(X x) {
      if (x instanceof A.B) { ... } // not working
   }
}
```

Is there a way to verify if some object (x) is actually the inner class (B) of some class (A) in this scenario?

I'm getting this error, but I unfortunately have no control over the classes A and B.

> The type A.B is not visible

Comment: Not unless you can make the inner class public (or move your caller into the same package as A).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this answer as a comment, but with a little reflection (the thinking kind, not the coding kind!), I'm turning it into an answer.

Since you don't have control over A or B, and B has package access, you can only see it from classes that are in the same package as A.  So what you could do - if you don't want to move C into the same package - is write a utility class - call it U - that has a boolean function, taking an X and returning whether it's an instance of A.B.

Comment: +1: A little reflection (the coding kind, not the thinking kind) might actually be able to do this.  But it's not the way to go.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I added a new package with the same name as the package in which A is located to my project and am able to access A.B within a helper class.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question - or even whether it's for me or @donroby.

Comment: Sorry I was asking what @donroby meant to say because I didn't understand his question.

Comment: He meant tha Java reflection could be used for this, but it would be a bad way to go.

Comment: Sorry if I introduced confusion here.  I was mainly riffing on Carl's phrase about reflection. Carl's explanation of my meaning is correct.